# Babel for relay and react-native-drawer

Tags: react-native, babeljs, relayjs

I’m trying to use `relay` along with `react-native-drawer` but it gives me `_this.state.viewport` is undefined. I’ve narrowed down the problem to babel but not sure now to proceed. (edited)

I got there after reading this issue https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer/issues/140 (edited)

`relay` uses

```
{
  "passPerPreset": true,
  "presets": [
    {"plugins": ["./plugins/babelRelayPlugin"]},
    "react-native"
 ]
}
```

and I think that’s the problem (edited)

I tried using `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` but doesn’t seem to help

Comment: +1 having the same issue and I have Relay also. When have drawer working and added Relay, I had issues with babel-relay-plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution and created a template. Summary is using react-native-router-flux and babel-relay-plugin-loader

https://github.com/hiaw/rn-relay-drawer-template